# how do I use custom types for objects under globalThis?

Tags: mysql, typescript, global-variables, typeerror

## Problem

I’m building a TypeScript express app with mysql. After initializing DB connection pool `const pool = mysql.createPool(...)`, I want to attach the created `Pool` object to `globalThis.pool` so I can access it elsewhere.

But doing so will cause type error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

After a bit of research I found that I need to declare `pool` globally in a `d.ts` files so I did this inside `global.d.ts`:

`declare var pool: any;`

However I immediately noticed that by doing so I lose the auto-complete feature beacause I'm setting `globalThis.pool` to `any` type. I then changed the declaration to

```
import Pool from "mysql/lib/Pool";
declare var pool: Pool;
```

but this deactivates my `global.d.ts` file as if it does not exist, and I'm getting that first type error again.

## How I expect it to work

able to assign types for global variables

```
declare var pool: Pool;
```

## Question

What is the correct way to define global variable in TS? I don't want to use any IOC framework because this is supposed to be a small and simple project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `Pool` type not having an index signature (guess you already guessed that from the error). This pretty much means that if you access any property that is not specifically typed in `Pool` is treated as `any`.

If you type your `global.d.ts` like this:

```
import Pool from "mysql/lib/Pool";
declare var pool: Pool;  // pool already has the type 'Pool', this does exactly nothing
```

then you are just telling TypeScript what it already knew: `pool` is of type `Pool`.
What you have to do is add your custom field, which is not typed specifically in `Pool` to that type.

```
import Pool from "mysql/lib/Pool";

// Either add an index signature
declare var pool: Pool & {[key:string]: PoolInstance}; // On the right hand, use the type that Pool instance has

// or add all your custom fields specifially (this is preferred because of stronger typing)

declare var pool: Pool & {pool: PoolInstance}; // Same here, use the type that Pool instance has
```

Since I am not familiar with the `Pool` type, I used `PoolInstance` as a placeholder for whatever the instance type is that `mysql.createPool(...)` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding is that I am missing index signature for 'globalThis' but not the 'pool' object. The returned type of pool instance is just 'Pool'. The problem is that in order to use ambient type declaration, the 'global.d.ts' needs to be clear from root level imports. I cannot import type 'Pool' and assign it to 'pool'. As soon as i remove the import statement and use 'any' for 'pool', it works. But i lose auto complete because pool is now 'any' type

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood then. Try importing using a dynamic import - this should not mark the global.d.ts as a module `declare var pool: import("mysql/lib/Pool");`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution was simple but effective!